# Give an upper bound for a function satisfying $f(n)=4f(n−1)+n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, computability, recursion, recursive-algorithms

A function $f(n)$ satisfies the recurrence $f(n)= 4f(n−1)+n$ for real numbers. Give an upper bound for $f(n)$.

Is the attached picture the correct answer?

[image: The answer I get so far is in this link. Click here]

Comment: You can verify this by trying some values. Also, you need to understand the Master Method (unless you want just the result, and in this case, you need to mention this), see for example:http://techieme.in/solving-recurrences-master-method/

Comment: How is $T(n)=4T(n/2)+n$ supposed to be related to $f(n)=4f(n-1)+n$?

Comment: A recurrence must stop somewhere. Where does yours stop?

Comment: The "attached picture" is more of a Hint than a complete answer.  It asks you to make a change of variables, or indeed it is a different but similar problem that you could build upon using a change of variables.

Answer (score 4):

Using Brute force here is not that ugly. Define: $u(n)=\frac{f(n)}{4^n}$. Then we have to look at :
$$
u(n)=u(n-1)+\frac{n}{4^n}
$$
which is a very easy to solve:
$$
u(n)=u(0)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{4^k}< u_0+\frac 49=c
$$
hence $f(n)<c4^n$. This is a tight upper bound because it is the supremum of $f(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, and I can write it like O(4^n) aswell?

Comment: The lower bound is really trivial; just see $f(n)>4f(n-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to understand it, how did you get the u(n) = u(n-1) + n/4^n. Was it by substituting U(n) you defined into T(n) = 4T(n/2)?

Comment: Honestly I share the same concern as Did about $T(n)$ and how did you get this equation. But if you just replace $f(n)$ by $u(n)4^n$ in the original equation you will get $u(n)=u(n-1)+\frac n{4^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ,master's method is not applicable here because the difference between f(n) and $n^{\log_ba}$ is not polynomial.Other than master's method ,you can solve it directly rather in a long but credible solution by putting $n=log_2m$,
so that the expression becomes:-
$$f(\log_{2} m)=4f(\log_2\frac{m}{2})-\log_2m\tag{..1}$$
i.e.$$S(m)=4S(m/2)-\log m\tag{..2}$$
thereby
$$S(m)=4^2S(\frac{m}{2^2})-4\log \frac{m}{2}-\log m\implies S(m)=4^2S(\frac{m}{2^2})-\left(\log\frac{m^{4^0+4^1}}{2^{0\times4^0+1\times 4^1}}\right)$$
Generalization:-
$$\implies S(m)=4^kS\left(\frac{m}{2^k}\right)-\left(log\frac{m^{4^0+.....4^{k-1}}}{2^{0\times4^0+....+(k-1)\times4^k}}\right)$$
Now we have sum of n terms of geometric progression:-
$$S_G=a\frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1}\tag{...3}$$
and sum of n terms of arithmetico - geometric progression:-
$$S_{AG}=\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{dr(1-r^{n-1})}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{(a+(n-1)d)r^n}{1-r}\tag{..4}$$
From eq.(3.) and (4.)

$$\implies S(m)=4^kS\left(\frac{m}{2^k}\right)-\left(\log\frac{m^\frac{4^k-1}{3}}{2^{\frac{4^{k+1}-3k4^k-4}{9}}}\right)$$
If $S(1)=1$ .i.e $k=\log_2 m$
and Since $n=\log_2 m \implies m=2^n $ & $n=k$
$$\implies S(m)=4^kS\left(\frac{m}{2^k}\right)-n\frac{4^k-1}{3}+\frac{4^{k+1}-3k4^k-4}{9}$$
$$\implies T(n)=5\times 4^n-6n4^n+3n-4\implies T(n)=\theta (4^n)$$